# If .NET 3.5 SP1 is missing, can I install 4 directly?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

When I need functions from .NET 3.5 SP1 on a system lacking it, is it safe to install .NET 4, or do I need to install .NET 3.5 SP1 also?

Comment: You also have to provide a .config file for the app to tell the CLR that using .NET 4.0 is okay,  `<supportedRuntime>` element.  Since the machine will have neither 3.5 nor 4.0, installing 3.5 is rather the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 4.0 have no relations to .NET 3.5 (.NET 2.0 runtime). It has its own runtime, .NET 4.0 completely separate from .NET 3.5 and lower .NET versions.

So you may install .NET 4.0 without care that you have missing .NET 3.5 SP1. But keep in mind that some applications may require .NET 3.5 SP1. Anyway there is shouldn't be any problems to install .NET 3.5 SP1 later.

Answer (score 1):

short response:  yes, it's compatible

long response: if you plan to install it on a customer computer, ensure it's policy does allow this version (big company sometimes need to approve each version of an application before installing it).

[edit] it's compatible but require a tigh modification in the config file http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/08/03/installing-net-framework-v4-0-and-running-net-2-0-3-0-3-5-3-5sp1-applications.aspx

Comment: I don't think I would recommend modifying the config file without a very good reason to do so. Why not just install .NET 3.5 if your application requires it?

Comment: @cody: it's a reasonable point of view. Installing another product or changing x applications are two possibilities. The X value is weighty in the balance

Answer (score 1):

If your application targets the .NET 2.0 runtime (used by .NET 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5) and uses functionality from SP 1 of .NET 3.5, you need to install the service pack.

Because .NET 4.0 runs on a different runtime, you can install it without issue side by side.

If your application will be running on the .NET 4.0 runtime, you do not need to install the service pack.